# How to install google chrome for ubuntu- touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, google-chrome

How to install google chrome for ubuntu- touch? Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Google Chrome website, Google has not made Chrome available for Ubuntu.  Please contact them for further details.

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/mobile/index.html

Comment: This is *mobile* Chrome, not desktop Chrome. Desktop Chrome *is* available for desktop Ubuntu. How might *desktop* Chrome be installed on Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: In March 2015, the answer was simply: "It can't be."  The answer today is probably still "it can't be," except this time it's because Google doesn't offer general Linux Chrome binaries for armhf.  Regardless, desktop Chrome is a different question, and should be asked with a new question such as "How do I install Google Chrome on an Ubuntu phone or tablet?"