# How can Google Chrome be installed on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, google-chrome, android, aquaris

I want to experiment with the [App Runtime for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) (ARC) in Google Chrome in order to see if Android applications can run easily in Ubuntu Touch. In order to do this, I first need to install Google Chrome. Given that this is merely an experiment and that I am not concerned with having to reflash my device (Aquaris E4.5), how can this be done?

At a quick guess, could Chrome be installed on Ubuntu Touch in the following way?

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo su -c 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Following this, an XMir launcher would likely be needed to run Chrome. How could this be written?

---

EDIT: Please note that I'm talking about desktop Chrome running on Ubuntu Touch, not mobile Chrome.

Comment: @PhilUK Thanks for your comment. No, I'm talking about desktop Chrome running on Ubuntu Touch, not mobile Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is you cant , cause it is not supported for neither your device nor any ubuntu phone. And by the way you cant install 64bit package in a arm system.Sorry for that!

I tried that ARC welder in Google Chrome but all in vain it never works flawlessly , developers have to work more upon it!If you are trying to run some android app , give a shot to [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here and therefore is a possible duplicate [How to install Google chrome for Ubuntu- touch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599021/how-to-install-google-chrome-for-ubuntu-touch). There answer here, was that Google has not made Chrome available for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thaks for your comment. No, I'm talking about desktop Chrome running on Ubuntu Touch, not mobile Chrome.